# get active email id combined with row number using app scripts google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

active user email id combined with the row number and current date, month, year, hours, minutes, seconds (e.g.: "mrx@gmail.com + row num + 06/08/2020 - 10:08:25" without any space, +, -,:, symbols. the format should be like this "mrx@gmail.com106082020100825") has to appear in column A if the same row is having any data in column E and disappear if the same row in column e is deleted.

Answer (score 1):

First Time you asked question:

```
function onMyEdit(e){
  //e.source.toast('Entry');
  console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=='Sheet1' && e.range.columnStart==5 && e.range.rowStart>1) {
    if(e.range.getValue()!='') {
      //e.source.toast('conditional');
      e.range.offset(0,-4).setValue(e.user + '\n' + e.range.rowStart);
    }else{
      e.range.offset(0,-4).setValue('');
    }
  } 
}
```

After the Edit:

```
function onMyEdit(e){
  //e.source.toast('Entry');
  console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=='Sheet1' && e.range.columnStart==5 && e.range.rowStart>1) {
    if(e.range.getValue()!='') {
      //e.source.toast('conditional');
      e.range.offset(0,-4).setValue(e.user + e.range.rowStart + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"dd/MM/yyyyHH:mm:ss"));
    }else{
      e.range.offset(0,-4).setValue('');
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: when I run it, it's showing "TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined (line 4, file "Code")"

Comment: How did you run it

Comment: I clicked on the triangle button in the script editor and also I tested typing some text in column e but no result.

Comment: You can't run functions that require onEdit trigger event object from the script editor. Unless you provide the event object.

Comment: I always build these functions wiith an installable trigger and test them in place from the page using console.log and e.source.toast()

Comment: I don't have any basic knowledge regarding the terminology ur using but if u can guide me instep wise, I can fix it.